# Insert float value to Mysql with Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

I am trying to save a float value into my MySql db. However after the below code was implemented with no errors the row is not inserted in the db. I am guessing that it is because my float value contains an "f".

Any ideas on how I can overcome this issue?

Thanks!

```
UserBean tailbean = new UserBean();

tailbean.setImei(555555559999f);
tailbean.setName("Rao");
tailbean.setPassword("hhh");
session = getSession();
session.beginTransaction();
session.save(tailbean);
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

Comment: Your float does not *contain* an f. Thats just the syntax for differentiating floats from other possible numeric values. Your problem lays elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You are constructing a proper java float, Its value does not include `f`, the f is mostly to make the compiler realize this is a floating number at first place, but from then on it is treated as proper float number.

Maybe the number is too large for a `float`: it has 32 bits and the number you enter does not fit in such range.

Maybe you would need to use `double` and the suffix `d`?